# Can I install dual ROS version on the same machine?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have ROS jade  running on Ubuntu 15.04. Now ROS Indigo has been released?

Can I install Indigo  alongside of jade and run both as needed?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243347/can-i-install-dual-ros-version-on-the-same-machine?/) by [fereydoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27370/fereydoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-08**:
I think you mean Kinetic. From older to newer: Indigo --> Jade --> Kinetic

**Comment by [fereydoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27370/fereydoon/) on 2016-09-08**:
thanks for your answer to me but  I really want to use best distr of ROS
indeed now I installed  jade and my friends say to me I should install indigo
Actually I am totally confused if you cam help me

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-08**:
If possible, I would go with Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) + ROS Indigo. If not, Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) + ROS Kinetic. I would avoid 15.04 + Jade as they are *not* long-term supported (LTS) distributions.

**Comment by [fereydoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27370/fereydoon/) on 2016-09-09**:
thanks a lot for your answer to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), Indigo is not being build for 15.04:

> Indigo Igloo (May 2014)

> - Ubuntu Saucy (13.10)

- Ubuntu Trusty (14.04 LTS)

(from [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)).

> Can I install Indigo alongside of jade and run both as needed?

That would be possible, but not on Ubuntu 15.04, only one 14.04 (and Gazebo could be a problem).

On 15.04 you *might* be able to build everything from source, but that can be involved.

PS: Indigo is 'older' than Jade.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fereydoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27370/fereydoon/) on 2016-09-08**:
thanks for your answer to me

I know Indigo is 'older' than Jade. but i think distr jade of ROS not good for me because i'm elementary in ROS and don't have information about which one of distr is good with my research about this because some package not supported with jade.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-08**:
Then I would suggest downgrading your Ubuntu installation to 14.04 (Ubuntu Trusty), and then installing Indigo.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per my knowledge, installing two versions of ROS on a single machine causes problem. What most of the people do is, they have two Virtual Machines for example in my case, I have two operating system in my Virtual Machines. One is Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS-Indigo and the other one is Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS-Kinetic. That's the best and avoid any possible conflict.

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-09**:
I'm sorry you've had that experience, but it's perfectly possible to have multiple ROS versions on a single Linux installation. In fact, on Ubuntu Precise, I've had 3 versions of ROS: fuerte, groovy and hydro. Only in special cases (Gazebo pkgs) do Indigo and Jade collide.

**Comment by [fereydoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27370/fereydoon/) on 2016-09-09**:
thanks a lot for your answer to me gvdhoorn and Dr Abdul Mannan